# Google map V3 usage limit in Phonegap applications

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cordova

I was wondering what is the limit of Google maps in Phone gap applications .

Since  API v3 doesn't require any key. So then in what basis they will be enforcing the limit? Is it per device?

If it's per device then we don't have to get the license key. Because our app usage  cross 250000 requests in a day. But otherwise we have to get the license key.

If anyone has any knowledge in this please share the information.

Answer (score 1):

You need an API key to access the google map api from javascript as mentioned here:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial .

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE"
  type="text/javascript"></script>`

This API key is what identifies you application. You can make as many clients as you want, but all the request the clients send to google are considered for calculating the total number of requests from you application.

**[Edit]**

Yes it is true that API_KEY is optional, but you never know till when. Using a key brings in the benefit of using statistics reporting. For Business it is the CLIENT_ID that is the key. 
About your question on how google determines the excessive usage of API, they have the referrer and also the document.url. **Using phonegap google may have hard time pointing your app out ;) but if you have such high traffic, it is recommended that you use an API key for central monitoring.**

**[Edit-2]**

According to this Link:

`2,500 requests may be sent to the Geocoding Web Service per day from a single IP address. This is independent of any geocoding activity generated by applications using one of the client Maps APIs for geocoding. Maps API Premier quotas remain unchanged.`
So the most prominent measure google has is, the user IP. So you get the API limit imposed by google per IP.

Comment: From V3 api key is not a mandatory one, although its recommended. I want to know how it gets calculated for phonegap apps if we dont give the key

Comment: Yeah that's what I also thought. But I need a solid proof. So I thought of doing a load testing.